# Getting a 1D array from a 3D array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 3d

I have a 8x8x3 array with some values. What I want to do is make a list of just the 1D arrays.

What I've got so far:

```
int[] packIt(int[,,] data, int factor) {
            List<int[]> toReturn = new List<int[]>();
            int[] test = data[0, 0];
```

So unless I'm missing something, I make a list of one dimensional arrays and try to fit in the one dimensional array at data[0, 0] (the test is just a placeholder so far). The error I'm getting is "Wrong number of indices", however if I follow the data[0,0,0] (which gives no error) I'll just get the 1 value at the location. I could do it manually, but am just wondering if there is an implementation for the functionality that I'm trying to do, as I will be using it a lot. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What's the order of element components in the resulting array? item 1's X, Y, Z, item 2's X, Y, Z, etc?

Comment: @gunr2171 if data[0, 0] = { X, Y ,Z }, then i would like test[] to be { X, Y, Z }. Hope that makes sense - toReturn[0] =  { X, Y, Z }, toReturn[1] =  { X, Y, Z }.

Comment: Data has 3 index components, so `data[0, 0]` is missing a number.

Comment: Yes but I am storing 3 values at data[0, 0] I would like to store data[0,0,0], data[0,0,1] and data[0,0,2] (all of the subvalues) into another array. I guess manually is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything specific to turn a 3D array into a 1D one; you can just enumerate it:

```
foreach(var x in multiDim)
  ...
```

This will print 1 to 8:

```
            var x = new int[2,2,2];
    x[0,0,0] = 1;
    x[0,0,1] = 2;
    x[0,1,0] = 3;
    x[0,1,1] = 4;
    x[1,0,0] = 5;
    x[1,0,1] = 6;
    x[1,1,0] = 7;
    x[1,1,1] = 8;
    
    foreach(int i in x)
      Console.WriteLine(i);
```

To this end you can just straight enumerate your array in chunks of whatever:

```
var out = new List<int[]>();
var arr = new int[chunkSize];
out.Add(arr);
var idx = 0;
foreach(var x in miltiDimArray){
  if(idx == chunkSize){
    out.Add(arr = new int[chunkSize]);
    idx = 0;
  }
  arr[idx++] = i;
}
```

Note that I don't try to make the ticks array smaller if the chunk size doesn't divide into the number of elements. idx will have a residual value you can use to work out what to resize the last array by if that is important